# How to skip alert 'Do you want uninstall this app' when click button

Tags: xamarin.android

After doing void uninstallApp , an alert 'Do you want to uninstall this app' appears. When click ok, delete the application.
Now I want to ignore this alert and delete the app is it possible
`

```
public void uninstallApp()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDelete);
            intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + "appname"));
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, removing the alert is impossible.

That is determined by the system. This confirmation pop-up alert is available to prevent you from deleting the app by mistake.